# How can i create custom roles and capabilities based on geolocalization in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm building a blog in wordpress with different Editors and contributors based on their geolocation,  i'll explain the problem:

Let's suppose we have four users:

1) Contributor from New York;
2) Editor from New York;
3) Contributor from Miami;
4) Editor from Miami.

What i need is that, the post created by the Contributor from New York, can be approved and published only by the editor From New York, and not by the one from Miami.
The same goes for the contributor from Miami.

In practice i need to create a univocal relationship between a Contributor and an Editor of the same city.

EDITOR[City A] can only approves post from CONTRIBUTOR[City A]
EDITOR[City B] can only approves post from CONTRIBUTOR[City B]
EDITOR[City A] can't approves post from CONTRIBUTOR[City B]
EDITOR[City B] can't approves post from CONTRIBUTOR[City A]

How can i achieve this in wordpress? I'm using the city as a category in my posts to limit a contributor to create posts  only of his city, but how can i restrict an editor to approves and publishes only the post from a contributor of his same city?

Comment: You could use geolocate reverse which I believe can be provided by Google Api. When you determined what city the user is from you could filter the posts based on the location of the user that posted it. It will be faster if you have already stored the city in the user_meta/post_meta(of the post). Are you trying to achieve this in the posts view in wp-admin?

Comment: Contributors that subscribe via form set their home city. Then i use the city to create a category for post, with the city categories i limit contributors to write post only in their own city category. So the problem is with editors, in fact i don't know how to bound them to approves only the posts from contributors of their same city and the posts of every contributor. 
PS Every contributor or editor set is city with a form.